# Eliminar una etiqueta html y el contenido que encierra

Tags: jquery

Me gustaría poder eliminar de una variable la etiqueta `<span> contenido </span>`

Tarea: `<span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-pause'></span>` Texto válido.

Solo debería aparecer Tarea: Texto válido

Comment: Hola, creo que tienes suficiente reputación para saber como funciona el sitio, debes incluir el código que has intentado usar y ne base a ese código te ayudaremos a encontrar una solución óptima.

Comment: He  leido antes de escribir la pregunta pero no he encontrado nada que valga. Respecto a las pruebas, tienes razón pero no he encontrado nada con lo que empezar a probar.

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso específico se puede hacer lo siguiente:

> Nótece que le he agregado un **DIV** que contiene tú código **HTML**, y le he puesto un `ID` para facilitar la captura en el ejemplo.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="miDiv">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pause'></span>Texto Válido
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#miDiv").children("span:first").remove();
```

**Explicación**

Primero con `$("#miDiv")` capturamos el elemento padre que tiene un **ID** (que en mi ejemplo es un elemento **DIV**), luego accedemos con el método `children("span")` a los hijos del elemento padre, que corresponden a elementos **SPAN**, también se puede apreciar que el parámetro además de `span` tiene `:first` que corresponde a un **pseudo-selector** que localiza el primer elemento.
Por último, llamamos al método `remove()` que elimina el elemento en cuestión.

**Aclaración**

Como `Texto Válido` no forma parte del elemento **SPAN**, es posible capturar el elemento **SPAN** en sí, para luego eliminarlo, lo que nos dejará el texto que queremos mantener.

**Lectura recomendada**

Puedes visitar los siguientes enlaces (en inglés) que corresponden a la documentación oficial de `jQuery`:

- [jQuery: método children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [jQuery: método remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [jQuery: seleccionando elementos](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría sería encerrar el valor de tu variable en un contenedor `div`, luego mediante un selector capturamos esa variable como si fuera un elemento `HTML` (que de hecho el valor de la misma es un elemento `HTML`) y obtenemos su contenido usando el método `.text()`

```js
var texto = "<div><span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-pause'></span> Texto válido.</div>";

console.log($(texto).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```